# Can't connect to the internet with static IP Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I'm running Ubuntu Server with VMware and I am trying to set up a static IP on it. I've written the following in /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        ens33:
            dhcp: no
            addresses: [192.168.1.101/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.1.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

I can't connect to the internet after doing this, I've tested with `sudo apt-get update` and it cannot resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

I'm quite new to this and any help would be much appreciated :D

Comment: Try to ping 8.8.8.8, if that works it means there is fault in your DNS.
Then write the result in comment.

Comment: From 192.168.1.101 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

Comment: you say you're using VMware, is this VMware Workstation?  Or full-blown VMware ESXi server running the VM?  I've used both products on a regular basis and can probably shed a little bit of light here

Comment: Just VMware Workstation, I downloaded the ISO from ubuntu.com

Comment: And what is your gateway ? Router or another VM machine ?

Comment: And what network segment is the VM on?  NAT?  Bridged?  Host-only?  Do you know if the network that it's using has DHCP enabled or not on it within VMware?

Comment: @JohnRonald Given that this is a VM on VMware workstation, let's wait to hear which segment they placed the VM on.  That'll determine the answer to your question.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's DHCP enabled or not. I bridged the VM when I set it up and the host machine is connected via ethernet

Comment: @Amy If it's using Bridged, then it's going to utilize the internet that your computer is using, if the static IP isn't working then it's likely that the settings you've set on the VM don't necessarily match the network itself.  What IP does the host computer have on the ethernet?  Is this workplace ethernet or your home ethernet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it! I added another network adapter that was NAT and that solved the issue. @Thomas Ward sparked my mind with his comment. Many thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Bridged will utilize your general network, but if you just need it 'up' and not accessible to other systems on the Ethernet, NAT will work to get you 'up and running' - you'll eventually want to start out with DHCP and Bridged if you intend to have other systems on your network reaching the system.